# Converting C structure to C++ class

Tags: c++, c, class, structure, iostream

I hope everyone had a great time with their families yesterday! While visiting my family out of town, I thought I'd get started on some of my projects with upcoming deadlines, one of which is converting a code written in C, which uses and array of structures to store and modify data, to a C++ code that uses an array of objects.  While I've recently become acquainted with C programming syntax, this will be my very first project in C++.  I understand that classes are supposed to be very similar to structures, but I'm confused about the syntax, as well as the concept of access specifiers. Below is my original C code, and the list of alterations to be made.  Any suggestions on how to get started, including good sources/tutorials for this kind of work would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your consideration!

Alterations:

1. declare all data in the class as private;
2. provide methods (class functions) that give all the required functionality
   for your program to work. In particular, declare a constructor method for
   the class.
3. besides the methods required by the program, write an access (\get") and
   mutator (\set") function for each private data member in the class.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//Function Prototypes
void insertFirstName(struct structureName[], char[], int);
void insertLastName(struct structureName[], char[], int);
void insertHomeNumber(struct structureName[], char[], int);
void insertCellNumber(struct structureName[], char[], int);
void printPhoneBook(struct structureName[], int);
int deleteFriend(struct structureName[], char[], int);
void showFriend(struct structureName[], char[], int);
void saveFile(FILE*, struct structureName[], int);
int loadFile(FILE*, struct structureName[]);

//Structure Declaration
typedef struct structureName{
   char *fName;  //member for First Name
   char *lName;  //member for Last Name
   char *hPhone; //member for Home Phone
   char *cPhone; //member for Cell Phone
} pbFriend;

int main(){

   int x = 0;
   int flag = 0; //returned in delete function to account for empty phonebook
   int entryCount = 0;//variable for count of entries
   int menuChoice = 0; //variable for switch statement
   int count = 0; //counter keeps track of entry numbers 
   char name[100] = {'\0'}; //place holder for entries
   pbFriend phoneBook[1000] = {'\0'}; //create instance
   char fileSave = '\0'; //variable for selection on file save query
   char fileLoad = '\0'; //variable for selection on file load query
   FILE *pbData; //file pointer

   do{
      //load file to phone book query
      printf("Welcome! Would you like to load a file into the phonebook? (y/n): ");
      scanf("%c",&fileLoad);
      getchar();

      if(fileLoad=='y'||fileLoad=='Y'){
         count = loadFile(pbData,phoneBook);
         printf("Success! File loaded!\n");
         entryCount = count;
      } //end if

      else{
         if(fileLoad!='n'&&fileLoad!='N'){
            printf("Invalid selection.\n");
         } //end if
      } //end else
   }while( fileLoad!='y'&&fileLoad!='Y'&&fileLoad!='n'&&fileLoad!='N');  //end do while

   do{
      //display menu                 
      printf("\nPhone Book Application\n");
      printf("1) Add friend\n");
      printf("2) Delete friend\n");
      printf("3) Show a friend\n");
      printf("4) Show phone book\n");
      printf("5) Quit\n");
      printf("What do you want to do?: ");
      scanf("%d",&menuChoice);
      getchar();
      switch(menuChoice){

      case 1:  //add friend case
         printf("\nFirst name: ");  //insert first name
         scanf("%s",name);
         getchar();
         //allocate memory
         phoneBook[count].fName = (char*)malloc(100*sizeof(char));

         //memory failed to allocate
         if(phoneBook[count].fName == NULL){
            printf("ERROR! Out of memory!");
         }//end if

         //memory allocated
         else{
            insertFirstName(phoneBook, name, count);   
         }//end else

         printf("Last name: "); //insert last name
         scanf("%s",name);
         getchar();

         //allocate memory
         phoneBook[count].lName = (char*)malloc(100*sizeof(char));

         //memory failed to allocate
         if(phoneBook[count].lName == NULL){
            printf("ERROR! Out of memory!");
         }//end if

         //memory allocated
         else{
            insertLastName(phoneBook, name, count);   
         }//end else

         printf("Phone number (home): "); //insert home number
         scanf("%s",name);
         getchar();

         //allocate memory
         phoneBook[count].hPhone = (char*)malloc(100*sizeof(char));

         //memory failed to allocate
         if(phoneBook[count].hPhone == NULL){
            printf("ERROR! Out of memory!");
         }//end if


         //memory allocated
         else{
            insertHomeNumber(phoneBook, name, count);   
         }//end else

         printf("Phone number (cell): "); //insert cell number
         scanf("%s",name);
         getchar();

         //allocate memory
         phoneBook[count].cPhone = (char*)malloc(100*sizeof(char));

         //memory failed to allocate
         if(phoneBook[count].cPhone == NULL){
            printf("ERROR! Out of memory!");
         }//end if

         //memory allocated
         else{
            insertCellNumber(phoneBook, name, count);   
         }//end else

         printf("Entry added to phone book!\n");
         printf("\n");
         count++;
         entryCount++;
         break;

      case 2:  //delete friend case
         printf("\nPlease provide a last name for entry deletion: ");
         scanf("%s",&name);
         getchar();
         strcat(name," "); //white space for string values
         flag = deleteFriend(phoneBook, name, count);

         //successful deletion
         if(flag == 1){
            printf("The entry has been deleted from the phonebook.\n");
            entryCount--;
         }//end if

         //no deletion
         else{
            printf("No deletion has been made.\n");
         } 
         printf("\n");
         break;

      case 3:  //show friend case
         printf("\n");
         printf("Please provide a last name: ");
         scanf("%s",&name);
         getchar();
         strcat(name," ");
         showFriend(phoneBook, name, count);
         printf("\n");
         break;

      case 4:  //show phone book case
         printf("\n");
         //empty phonebook
         if(entryCount == 0){
            printf("The phonebook is empty.\n");
         }//end if
         else{
            printPhoneBook(phoneBook, count);
         }//end else
         printf("\n");
         break;

      case 5:  //quit case
         do{
            printf("\nWould you like to save the phonebook to a file? (y/n): ");
            scanf("%c",&fileSave);
            getchar();

            switch(fileSave){
            case 'y': case 'Y': //save case
               saveFile(pbData,phoneBook,count);
               printf("Success! File saved!");
               break;       

            case 'n': case 'N': //exit without saving case 
               printf("Good bye!\n");
               break;

            default: //invalid case
               printf("Invalid selection.\n");
               break;
            } //end switch
         }while(fileSave!='y'&&fileSave!='Y'&&fileSave!='n'&&fileSave!='N'); //end do while
         break;

      default: //invalid case
         printf("Invalid menu choice.\n\n");
         break;
      }//end switch statement
   }while(menuChoice != 5); //end do while loop

   getch();
   return 0;
}//end main

//Function Definitions
//function to insert first name
void insertFirstName(pbFriend phoneBook[], char name[], int count){
   strcpy(phoneBook[count].fName, name);
   strcat(phoneBook[count].fName," ");  
}

//function to insert last name
void insertLastName(pbFriend phoneBook[], char name[], int count){
   strcpy(phoneBook[count].lName, name);
   strcat(phoneBook[count].lName," ");
}

//function to insert home phone number
void insertHomeNumber(pbFriend phoneBook[], char name[], int count){
   strcpy(phoneBook[count].hPhone, name);
   strcat(phoneBook[count].hPhone," ");
}

//function to insert cell phone number
void insertCellNumber(pbFriend phoneBook[], char name[], int count){
   strcpy(phoneBook[count].cPhone, name);
   strcat(phoneBook[count].cPhone," ");
}

//function to delete entry
int deleteFriend(pbFriend phoneBook[], char name[], int count){
   int x;
   int foundFlag = 0; //foundFlag for seeing if query is in structure
   char nullStr[30] = {'\0'}; //NULL string
   char name2[30] = {'\0'}; //string to store first name query
   //get first name to prevent multiple deletions due to same last name
   printf("Please provide the first name of the entry to be deleted: ");
   scanf("%s", &name2);
   getchar();
   strcat(name2," ");
   for(x=0;x<count;x++){
      if((strcmp(phoneBook[x].lName,name)==0)&&(strcmp(phoneBook[x].fName,name2)==0)){
         foundFlag = 1; //entry found, proceed with delete
         //free previously allocated memory
         free(phoneBook[x].fName);
         free(phoneBook[x].lName);
         free(phoneBook[x].hPhone);
         free(phoneBook[x].cPhone);
         //set free strings to NULL
         strcpy((phoneBook[x].fName), nullStr);
         strcpy((phoneBook[x].lName), nullStr);
         strcpy((phoneBook[x].hPhone), nullStr);
         strcpy((phoneBook[x].cPhone), nullStr);
      }//end if
   }//end for
   //entry not found
   if(foundFlag == 0){ 
      printf("\nSorry, there is nobody with that name in the phone book.\n");
   }//end if
   return foundFlag;
}//end function

//function to search entries by last name
void showFriend(pbFriend phoneBook[], char name[], int count){
   int x;
   int foundFlag = 0; //foundFlag for seeing if query is in structure
   printf("\n");
   for(x=0;x<count;x++){
      if(strcmp((phoneBook[x].lName), name) == 0){
         foundFlag = 1; //entry found, proceed with display
         printf("%s",phoneBook[x].fName);
         printf("%s",phoneBook[x].lName);
         printf("%s(home) ",phoneBook[x].hPhone);
         printf("%s(cell)",phoneBook[x].cPhone);
         printf("\n");
      }//end if   
   }//end for
   //entry not found
   if(foundFlag == 0){
      printf("Sorry, there is nobody with that name in the phone book.\n");
   }//end if                               
}//end function

//function to print phone book contents
void printPhoneBook(pbFriend phoneBook[], int count){
   int x;
   for(x=0;x<count;x++){
      //check to avoid NULL strings, which have been deleted
      if(strlen(phoneBook[x].fName) > 0){ 
         printf("%s", phoneBook[x].fName);
         printf("%s", phoneBook[x].lName);
         printf("%s(home) ", phoneBook[x].hPhone);
         printf("%s(cell)", phoneBook[x].cPhone);
         printf("\n");
      }//end if
   }//end for
}//end function

//function to save to a file
void saveFile(FILE *pbData, pbFriend phoneBook[], int count){
   char fileName[100] = {'\0'}; //string to store desired name to save file as
   int x = 0; //counter variable
   printf("Please enter the file name: ");
   scanf("%s",fileName);
   getchar();
   //open file
   pbData = fopen(fileName,"w");
   //file open fail case
   if(pbData == NULL){
      printf("ERROR! File not saved!\n");
      perror("The following error occurred"); //specifies i/o error
      getchar();
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE); //exit program with error
   } //end if
   //file open success case
   else{
      //write to file   
      for(x=0;x<count;x++){
         fprintf(pbData, "%s", phoneBook[x].fName);
         fprintf(pbData, "%s", phoneBook[x].lName);
         fprintf(pbData, "%s", phoneBook[x].hPhone);
         fprintf(pbData, "%s", phoneBook[x].cPhone);
      } //end for
      fclose(pbData);
   } //end else
}// end function

//function to load a file into the phone book
int loadFile(FILE *pbData, pbFriend phoneBook[]){
   char fileName[100] = {'\0'}; //variable to store name of file to load
   int count = 0; //counter variable
   char tabulaRasa[30] = {'\0'}; /*NULL string to clear garbage data from the
                                 last loop of the feof() condition when loading 
                                 files*/
   printf("Please enter the name of the file you wish to load: ");
   scanf("%s",fileName);
   getchar();
   //open file
   pbData = fopen(fileName,"r");
   //file open fail case
   if(pbData == NULL){
      printf("ERROR! Unable to load file!\n");
      perror("The following error occurred"); //specifies i/o error
      getchar();
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE); //exit program with error
   } //end nested if
   //file open success case
   else{
      //allocate memory to store data from a file
      while(!feof(pbData)){
         phoneBook[count].fName = (char*)malloc(100*sizeof(char));
         if(phoneBook[count].fName == NULL){
            printf("ERROR! Out of memory!");
         } //end double nested if
         phoneBook[count].lName = (char*)malloc(100*sizeof(char));
         if(phoneBook[count].lName == NULL){
            printf("ERROR! Out of memory!");
         } //end double nested if
         phoneBook[count].hPhone = (char*)malloc(100*sizeof(char));
         if(phoneBook[count].hPhone == NULL){
            printf("ERROR! Out of memory!");
         } //end double nested if
         phoneBook[count].cPhone = (char*)malloc(100*sizeof(char));
         if(phoneBook[count].cPhone == NULL){
            printf("ERROR! Out of memory!");
         } //end double nested if
         //load from file
         fscanf(pbData,"%s",phoneBook[count].fName);
         strcat(phoneBook[count].fName," "); 
         fscanf(pbData,"%s",phoneBook[count].lName);                         
         strcat(phoneBook[count].lName," ");
         fscanf(pbData,"%s",phoneBook[count].hPhone);
         strcat(phoneBook[count].hPhone," ");
         fscanf(pbData,"%s",phoneBook[count].cPhone);
         strcat(phoneBook[count].cPhone," ");
         count++; //show that entry/entries have been made from file
      }//end while loop
      //free memory of last entry (junk data from feof() condition)
      free(phoneBook[count-1].fName);
      free(phoneBook[count-1].lName);
      free(phoneBook[count-1].hPhone);
      free(phoneBook[count-1].cPhone);
      //set newly free strings to NULL
      strcpy((phoneBook[count-1].fName), tabulaRasa);
      strcpy((phoneBook[count-1].lName), tabulaRasa);
      strcpy((phoneBook[count-1].hPhone), tabulaRasa);
      strcpy((phoneBook[count-1].cPhone), tabulaRasa);
      count--;
   } //end nested else
   fclose(pbData);
   return(count); //show that phone book is not empty
} //end if
```

Comment: I hope while you were enjoying thanksgiving with your family, you have cared to run `indent` on your code.

Comment: `//end if`, `//end else`, seriously?

Comment: The only difference between a C++ class and struct is that structs' members are public by default and classes' members are private by default. Also in C++ you don't need the "typedef"

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @EricB also, `struct` inheritance is `public` by default.

Comment: I suggest you try and write the C++ version and if/when you run into  a problem you cannot solve then ask a specific question about that problem. Stackoverflow is a place for specific questions and not general advice or tutorials.

Comment: I hope that while everyone was enjoying bashing this poor person, he solved the issue :/

Answer (score 3):

A brilliant way to get started with the task at hand is to have a look at some of the items from the [C++ Getting Started](http://isocpp.org/get-started) page.